# What is the easiest way to connect a C# application to an Azure SQL server database using an Active directory Account?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to connect to an Azure SQL Server using Active directory password. According to what i've read i need to build my connection string using the userId of my Active directory domain and it's password:

```
SqlConnectionStringBuilder nuevaCadena = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
nuevaCadena.DataSource = "***.database.windows.net";
nuevaCadena.InitialCatalog = "dbname";
nuevaCadena.PersistSecurityInfo = false;
nuevaCadena.UserID = "my_email_registered_on-the-domain";
nuevaCadena.Password = "my-password";
nuevaCadena.MultipleActiveResultSets = false;
nuevaCadena.Encrypt = true;
nuevaCadena.TrustServerCertificate = false;
nuevaCadena.Authentication =     SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryPassword;
        conexionBase = nuevaCadena.ToString();

EntityConnectionStringBuilder entityBuilder =
            new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

entityBuilder.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
entityBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = conexionBase;
entityBuilder.Metadata = "metadata=res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl";
```

The context is instantiated but when i try to query some data:
  return context.motorizado.ToList();

I get the following error message:

> "An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException' occurred in >EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: At least one of the input paths is not valid because >either it is too long or it has incorrect format."

Answer (score 0):

entityBuilder.Metadata seems to have the wrong format.

Just have a try with this:

```
entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Models.Model1.csdl|res://*/Models.Model1.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model1.msl";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my input on this:

As @Allen mentioned , it seems to be in the wrong format, you could try something like below:

```
**cbuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl";**
```

Also ,consider moving your connection information out to your configuration file rather than build it in code file.

You can check below blog for additional tips:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/metadata-exception-in-entity-framework-connection-strings1

Hope it helps.